# Class 'Process' on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I'm tying to get Process.StartTime and Process.ExitTime in Exited event, but in first case I get 'Cannot process request because the process (8275) has exited.' and 'Process was not started by this object, so requested information cannot be determined.' in second. It works on windows.

What is the reason? And how I can get start and exit time?

Is it even possible?

```
void ProcExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process proc = (Process)sender;
    processes.Remove(proc);
    try
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine($"Dead: {proc.Id} {proc.ProcessName} ({proc.HasExited} | {proc.StartTime})");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine($"Dead: {proc.Id} {proc.ProcessName} ({proc.HasExited} | {exc.Message})");
    }
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

ProxExited called like:

```
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
proc.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcExited);
```

Through experiments, I found out that if you look at the start time before the OnExited event is called (beetwen ***), then the error will not pop up during the event. You cannot do the same with ExitTime.

```
void GetProcesses(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    var tmp = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
    var except = new List<Process>();
    foreach (var proc in tmp)
    {
        if (processes.FindIndex(p => p.ProcessName == proc.ProcessName) == -1) except.Add(proc);
    }
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.WriteLine($"Find new: {except.Count}");
    Console.ResetColor();
    foreach (var proc in except)
    {
        try
        {
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.Exited += ProcExited;
            Console.WriteLine($"New: {proc.Id} {proc.ProcessName} ***{proc.StartTime}*** {proc.HasExited}");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine($"New: {proc.Id} {proc.ProcessName} ({exc.Message})");
        }
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
    processes.AddRange(except);
    timer.Start();
}
```

GitHub link: https://github.com/Tulpash/Watcher.git

Comment: how did ProcExited get called?

Comment: update question, please check